# \setcounter{} is not affecting numbering

Tags: sectioning

I am trying to write my master thesis using a header file given by chair.

I'm trying to use `\subsubsection{}` which did not include any numbering, a quick google search reveals I need to use `\setcounter{}`

The format is as follows, I have a **master.tex** file which inputs **thesis_header.tex** and the **chapter2.tex**.

**thesis_header.tex:**

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[normal,small,bf]{caption}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
```

**main.tex:**

```
\input{thesis_header}
\begin{document}
% added abstract, chapter1 ...
\input{chapters/chapter2}
\end{document}
```

**chapter2.tex:**

```
\section{Finite Cell Method}
\label{sec:theory}

\subsection{Discretization}
\label{sec:FCM_Discretization}

\subsection{Integration}
\label{sec:FCM_Integration}

\subsubsection*{Adaptive Space Tree}
\label{sec:FCM_Space_Tree}

\subsubsection*{Moment Fitting Integration}
\label{sec:FCM_Moment_Fitting}

\subsection{Weakly Enforced Dirichlet and Neumann Boundary Conditions}
\label{sec:FCM_WeakBC}
```

**-- output --**

[image: ..]

My intended depth was:

> 1.3. Finite Cell Method
>
> > - 1.3.1 Discretization
> > - 1.3.2 Integration
> >
> > > - 1.3.2.1 Space Tree Integration
> > > - 1.3.2.2 Moment fitting Integration
> >
> > - 1.3.3 Weakly ...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! a MWE would help (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/120578)

Comment: @koleygr I will try and minimize as much as possible, for the 3 files in question.

Comment: Just leave the sectioning commands in there and may be some `\lipsum[]` if needed.

Comment: @koleygr this is a minimal example of what I am doing, in a second run I tried removing `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}` from the header and wrote it in main before `\begin(document)`. Same output.

Comment: Did you try `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}`? (I haven't tested this for lack of a proper MWE.)

Comment: The default for book is secnumdepth=3 (tocdepth=2).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is unrelated to `secnumdepth` it is simply that you have used `*`

```
 \subsubsection*{Adaptive Space Tree}
```

which is the un-numbered heading, this should be

```
 \subsubsection{Adaptive Space Tree}
```

Comment: You beat me to the answer by a minute. :-) I'll delete mine.

Comment: @Mico it probably took you that long to write all the extra text:-)

Comment: Thank you , I had been trying to make subsubsection work for a while, autocomplete showed me both. So at first I tried without the `*`, and the other had the same result. When I looked online and reassigned the `secnumdepth` to 3 or 4. I forgot I was still using  `subsubsection*{}`